# Updating value of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
weights = np.zeros(4) 
for row in trainData:
    iterRow= (row[:-1])             
    x=0           
for weight in weights:
    weight += (y*iterRow[x])
    print("weight is", weight)
    x +=1
print("new weights are" , weights"
```

- What I am trying to do is:

1. create a numpy array that is just [0,0,0,0]
2. For each row in my training dataset (approx 200), remove the last column
3. then- for each weight value, add the corresponding value of row that we are currently on and multiply by y (defined earlier in code)

My issue is that the new weights aren't updating correctly, and when I print them they're still [0,0,0,0]. However on the line above where i print "weight is", the updated weight will display there, it just doesn't translate into my numpy array
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how for loops work in Python. `for weight in weights` creates a new variable called `weight` at every iteration. `weight += (y*iterRow[x])` updates this variable, not the numpy array. Try this instead:

```
...
for i in range(len(weights)):
    weights[i] += (y*iterRow[x])
    print("weight is", weights[i])
    x +=1
...
```

Comment: thank you- perfect solution to a very silly mistake of mine :)

Comment: @user17840994  You are welcome. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.